# Find value of $k$ such that domain of $f(x)$ is $(-\infty \: 2] \cup [6 \:\infty)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms

Find value of $k$ such that domain of $$f(x)=\log_{0.5}\left(\log_{4}\left(\log_3[(x-k)^2]\right)\right)$$ is $(-\infty \: 2] \cup [6 \:\infty)$ where $[.]$ is Greatest integer function.

For outside $\log$ to take valid arguments we have $$ 0 \lt \log_{4}\left(\log_3[(x-k)^2]\right)\lt 1$$ which implies

$$1 \lt \log_3[(x-k)^2] \lt 4$$ $\implies$

$$3 \lt [(x-k)^2] \lt 81$$ $\implies$

$$(x-k)^2 \ge 4$$ and $$(x-k)^2 \le 81$$

From here how can we find $k$

Comment: You have the right idea, you need to find the valid argument range for each logarithm from the outside in. But why do you think that the argument of the outermost $\log_{0.5}$ needs to be smaller than $1$? $\log_{0.5}2 =-1$ without any problem.